# Is there a native function to get the prefix numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

```
'123xswer'
```

How to retrieve 123 from the string above without using regular expression?

Comment: Why can't you use a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> parseInt('123xswer', 10)
  123
```

(Leading zeros won't be kept.)

(The "10" is to specify we want decimal numbers, so that `099abcd` can return the expected integer.)

Answer (score -2):

Use `split` function .

```
var str='123xwer' ;
arr = str.split('x') ;
alert ( arr[0] ) ;
```